# What is the default transformResponse and transformRequest functions in $http

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, serialization

I'm wanting to serialize incoming and outgoing params. I've discovered I can do so by changing `transformRequest` and `transformResponse` default methods in `$http` config. My question is this. What is the default code inside these two functions? For the life of me I can't find out where it's at. In order for me to successfully serialize the params, I need to know what the original functions looked like. I'm currently running Angular 1.5.X. Thanks.

```
angular.module('coolApp')
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest = function(data){
    // What is the default code here?
    // I need to add {security_token: 'secret_code'} to the request
    // data sent to the server

  }

  $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse = function(data){
    // What is the default code here?
    // I need to remove the useless_params attribute in the response
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Default [`transformRequest`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/http.js#L290-L292) and [`transformResponse`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.8/src/ng/http.js#L135-L149) functions are defined in `$http` provider source code.

Comment: Although that is technically true the code is borrowing from numerous methods found within the source code. I'm looking for a solution to use within my app, not merely copy and paste from the source code. I was hoping AngularJS would have a solution to this since after all they allow you the ability to edit the function.

Comment: Please, update the question then, it is not clear what is your objective. The question says that you need to 'know' what the functions are, there's no mention of what you need this knowledge for.

Comment: The first sentence reads, "I'm wanting to serialize incoming and outgoing params". I'll update my answer to be clearer.

Comment: Sure, default transform methods could be patched with additional behaviour. But it looks like you have XY problem. This is what $http interceptors are for, they are there exactly to do things like that.